# Maven downloading dependent poms but not jars

Tags: java, maven-2

My project has a number of compile dependencies listed within its POM.

I've noticed that when installing the project (plain old `mvn install`) maven doesn't download some dependent jars, but does download their POM. This is causing issues when referencing my project downstream - to overcome this, I'm manually downloading them using the dependency plugin.

Is this expected behaviour from compile scoped dependencies?

Heres an extract of my POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    ......
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <scriptSourceDirectory>src/main/resources</scriptSourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>generated</exclude>
                    <exclude>log4j.properties</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>

        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>[2.5)</versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <execute />
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.neethi</groupId>
            <artifactId>neethi</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
        .........
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: Can you share your pom.xml?

Comment: Why are you downloading dependencies via maven-dependency-plugin does not make sense. Using the dependencies in the pom is the way to go in Maven. Furthermore what is the purpose to redefine default like `src/main/resources` and why excluding files from `src/main/resources`?

Comment: The dependency plugin is a bit of a red herring - I was playing with shaded jars and this plugin to provide easy access to the project for downstream stuff (a groovy script). I've now ditched that, so its redundant. I was under the assumption that I need to define the resources/other directories like this If I want to use them in parametrised bits of the build process.